# azure forced tunneling - route all traffic back through on prem firewall

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking, srx

configured a site to site vpn with azure and on prem juniper srx firewall. traffic in both direction is working. 
configured forced tunneling to route azure vm internet traffic too through on-prem firewall. It seems that internet traffic is not passing through the tunnel to the other side, all other traffic is. any suggestions?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-azvirtualnetworkgatewaydefaultsite?view=azps-2.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the default site to make the Force tunnel to work. Below are the sample command to set default site:

```
$LocalGateway = Get-AzLocalNetworkGateway -Name "DefaultSiteHQ" -ResourceGroupName "ForcedTunneling"
$VirtualGateway = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -Name "Gateway1" -ResourceGroupName "ForcedTunneling"

Set-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayDefaultSite -GatewayDefaultSite $LocalGateway -VirtualNetworkGateway $VirtualGateway
```

Also you can check your effective routes in the NIC for the default route next hop as Virtual Network Gateway.

Let me know if you have any further questions.